# Extract content in between two strings

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I have found numerous posts about this but nothing seems to be helping me. I have an html file and I am trying to extract a number in between two strings.
The string will look like the following (with a bunch of text before and after what is shown):

```
Results Found: <strong>4</strong>
```

I am wanting to extract the 4.
I have tried several things including the following:

```
sed -n 'Results Found: <strong>/,/<\/strong>/ { //!p }' find.html
sed 's/Results Found: <strong>\(.*\)<\/strong>/\1/' find.html
```

Neither of these are working correctly.

Comment: did you try this `sed -n 's/.*Results Found: <strong>\([^<>]*\)<\/strong>.*/\1/p' find.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below sed command.

```
sed -n 's/.*Results Found: <strong>\([^<>]*\)<\/strong>.*/\1/p' find.html
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks so much! I've been searching for hours on this and nothing seemed to work. Greatly appreciate your help!